# How i can see the DB in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

how i can see the "data" in my DB i try use Navicat but i don't know where is my db i'm using the Android Studio with IDE...

**My Emulator Configuration**

```
*Android 4.4.2 - API level 19
*Intel Atom (x86)
*RAM: 343
*VM HEAP: 32
*Internal Storage: 200 MiB
*SD Card: 200MiB
```

i use the DDMS for File Explorer, but i can't see my DB

> My path for my App is: Data\Data\com.example.yiquishum.savac4k\databases and i have two items.

1. Savac4K
2. Savac4K-journal

thanks :D!

Comment: use `sqlite3 <path-to>/Savac4k` you can run queries, etc

Comment: y type in the Terminal?

Comment: why not? i thought you wanted to see the data. do it on the device...or pull the database to your 'puter and do it there. same diff.

Comment: you see 2 files in the databases folder, but you don't know where the db is? I am confused here

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite Database Browser: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

I have do that with a real device, not with emulator. In case of real device, in console type:

```
adb shell
run-as com.example.yiquishum.savac4k
cat databases/database_file_name.db > /sdcard/database_file_name.db
exit
exit
adb pull /sdcard/database_file_name.db
```

And you will have the database file in your project root directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `adb` tool to get it. The database is located in `/data/data/<your package name>/databases`. The file name is `<database name>.db`.